# Error occurring while retrieving a csv data file in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, time-series

Given this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
dateparse = lambda dates : pd.datetime(date, '%Y-%m')
data = pd.read_csv('F2016_11_18_14-2016_11_18_21_datafile.csv', parse_dates='Date', index_col = 'Date', date_parser=dateparse)
print (data.head())
```

I get a TypeError:

> TypeError: Only booleans, lists, and dictionaries are accepted for the 'parse_dates' parameter

I don't understand why this is happening.

Here's a sample of my data:

```
Date        Time_GMT    Time_IST    Current
11/18/2016  9:00:00     14:30:00    20.9
11/18/2016  9:00:01     14:30:01    23.37
11/18/2016  9:00:02     14:30:02    24.11
11/18/2016  9:00:03     14:30:03    26.51
11/18/2016  9:00:04     14:30:04    28.9
11/18/2016  9:00:05     14:30:05    24.21
11/18/2016  9:00:06     14:30:06    23.21
```

Comment: Your `lambda` is ill-formed: `dateparse = lambda dates : pd.datetime(date, '%Y-%m')` should be `dateparse = lambda dates : pd.datetime(dates, '%Y-%m')`

Comment: Also is your sample data really looking this? is not comma separated? because if this is your sample data then your code should not work. If it is comma separated then edit your question, additionally you don't need the dateparse param this should work: `data = pd.read_csv('F2016_11_18_14-2016_11_18_21_datafile.csv', parse_dates='Date', index_col = 'Date')`

Comment: This is my data and can you please tell me how I should approach this problem.

Comment: Try `data = pd.read_csv('F2016_11_18_14-2016_11_18_21_datafile.csv', parse_dates='Date', index_col = 'Date', delim_whitespace=True)`

Comment: As the error says, `parse_dates` accepts only booleans, lists or dictionaries, so try this: `parse_dates=['Date']` instead of `parse_dates='Date'`

Comment: For the record, I had a very similar error, and @MaxU suggestion solved it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the error says, `parse_dates` accepts only booleans, lists or dictionaries, so try this: `parse_dates=['Date']` instead of `parse_dates='Date'`